# Passing the values to the fraction class in java

Tags: java, fractions

If i was to make a new program and wanted to have a fraction class and what my book calls a driver class wich is a main class and i have code like this

```
// Driver class

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DriverClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Fraction c, d;

        System.out.println(" Enter a numerator then a denominator:");
        c = new Fraction( stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
        c.print();

       System.out.println(" Enter a numerator then a denominator:");
        d = new Fraction( stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
        d.print();
    }
}
...
```

in my fraction class i have a method called public fraction. How will that set both numbers from fraction c in the driver class wich is coming in from the scanner util and also would this, would the c values be replaced by the values that are coming in from fraction d? I am taking a Java class and this is part the part of my home work I dont understand. I am trying to get these valued passed to the fraction class because in the end i have to add these two fractions together and also multiply them.

```
// begining of class

public class Fraction{

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    // well this is what my problem is, how do I call for c 
    // twice in the Fraction class
    public int Fraction(int num, int denom){

this.numerator = num;

this.denominator = denom;
}
    // is this the right way to recieve the fraction 
    // from the driver class for both c and d?

}
```

can any one help me with this one

Comment: why did you not edit your old post? I wrote an answer...

Comment: I may have squashed some edits when I formatted the code; this was unintentional. Apologies. FYI: details on how to post code in Markdown here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Im sorry i was trying to edit my old post because alot of people did not understand me and i was trying to help them understand me and i am on a goverment computer so alot of stuff was not clear to me on this site. I am trying to write a program for school but I dont understand it that much. I am on Duty right now so I am doing a thousand things at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Fraction` method is a method which is defined to return an int, but you're calling it as though it were a constructor.

Constructors don't return anything, so don't declare any return type. ( they don't even have a `void` type so the compiler knows they are constructors rather than methods, and need to be called with `new`. It's a minor bug that Java lets you declare methods with the same name as the class, IIRC one of the puzzles in [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) does that ).

Remove the "`int`" return type from the definition:

```
public class Fraction{

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public  Fraction(int num, int denom) {
        //...
```

> How will that set both numbers from fraction c in the driver class wich is coming in from the scanner util and also would this, would the c values be replaced by the values that are coming in from fraction d?

You're making two calls to `new Fraction(..,..)`. Each time you use `new`, it creates a new object of the requested class and then calls the constructor on that object with the values you give it. So `c` and `d` will hold references to difference instances of `Fraction`. As the `numerator` and `denominator` fields of `Fraction` are not marked as `static`, then each instance of `Fraction` will have its own copy of those fields, so the values passed to the constructor of the object whose reference will stored in the variable `c` are stored in the first new object, and those of `d` in the second new object. As they are different objects, the values won't replace each other.

Comment: Constructors don't return anything?  Not even an instance of the type defined by the class?

Comment: No. The instance is allocated, then dup'd on the stack then the constructor ( renamed to <init> ) is called. Have you ever seen a constructor which ends in a return statement.

Comment: I am very new to Java and learned a little of vb and c++ back in the day. Like in 98 but I dont remeber that stuff and I am a little confused on this project i am doing.

Comment: What would happened if I needed to add those two fractions together and then print it.

Comment: You would need to create an plus() method which returned a new fraction representing the sum of the two fractions. You also would want a toString() method which converted the fraction to a string, and then you could call System.out.println( c.plus(d) )

Comment: Pete what you said on the first comments helped me understood again that the c and d are new objects holding its place and even though my book says that as well I am still a little confused. I just want to say thanks alot I needed that.

Comment: How would you add the numerators and denominators in a plus statement, what I tried to do was put add() int x = this.numerator(c) + this.numerator(d) I dont understand.

Comment: Ask a new question and post the code you're working on rather than using comments on this one.